# Get queue repeated same values count

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Given table/data like this:

```
WITH T(col1, col2) AS(
    SELECT 1, 'A' FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'B' FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 'B' FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 'B' FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, 'A' FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 6, 'B' FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 7, 'B' FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 8, 'A' FROM DUAL
)
```

I need get `col2` queue repeated counts, I mean, how many times repeated same value in `col2` when rows are ordered by `col1`

Result must be:

```
col1 | col2 | queue_count
-------------------------
1    |A     |1
2    |B     |3
3    |B     |3
4    |B     |3
5    |A     |1
6    |B     |2
7    |B     |2
8    |A     |1
```

I tried some analytic functions but don't achieve desirable result.

It's possible to do this in "pure" SQL? without using pl/sql  (without looping and each row step by step handling, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a gap and islands problem.  Here is one way to solve it:

```
select col1, col2,
       count(*) over (partition by col2, seqnum - seqnum_col2) as queue_count
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by col2 order by col1) as seqnum_col2,
             row_number() over (order by col1) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t;
```

It is a little hard to explain why this works.  However, if you run the subquery and stare at the results, you will probably "get" why the difference between the row numbers works to identify adjacent rows with the same value in `col2`.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for posting input data for testing in a factored subquery, greatly appreciated!

You didn't mention your Oracle version (that should be included in every question, since different versions allow different solutions); in any case, for anyone with Oracle 12 and above, there is a very simple and efficient solution using MATCH_RECOGNIZE.

```
WITH T ( col1, col2 ) AS (
       SELECT 1, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
       SELECT 2, 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
       SELECT 3, 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
       SELECT 4, 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
       SELECT 5, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
       SELECT 6, 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
       SELECT 7, 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
       SELECT 8, 'A' FROM DUAL
     )
select col1, col2, queue_count
from   t
match_recognize (
  order by col1
  measures final count(*) as queue_count
  all rows per match
  pattern ( A+ | B+ )
  define  A as A.col2 = 'A',
          B as B.col2 = 'B'
)
;

 COL1 COL2  QUEUE_COUNT
----- ---- ------------
    1 A               1
    2 B               3
    3 B               3
    4 B               3
    5 A               1
    6 B               2
    7 B               2
    8 A               1

 8 rows selected
```